# ¿Cómo puedo Interpretar error en la consola? - Fusion Builder no funciona

Tags: wordpress, console

Tengo un error en mi página que al parecer, hacer que mi portfolio no cargue:
http://www.baroniarialb.cat/portfolio-items/la-rectoria-de-la-torra/

El contenido está cargado y antes funcionaba, pero ahora no puedo ver nada. Uso el tema AVADA y WPML para traducir. Si me ayudan a corregir ese error, gracias.

El código de error en la consola es el siguiente:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.noticeContainer is null
init http://www.baroniarialb.cat/wp/wp-content/plugins/cookie-notice/js/front.min.js?ver=2.1.0:1
<anonymous> http://www.baroniarialb.cat/wp/wp-content/plugins/cookie-notice/js/front.min.js?ver=2.1.0:1
```

Comment: Bienvenid@ a [es.so], te recomiendo hacer el [tour] y leer [ask] para que sepas como preguntar y que elementos necesitamos para apoyarte

Comment: gracias por la recomendación! Alguna respuesta a mi pregunta?

Comment: Primero activa el wp-debug y revisa el error log, verifica si wordpress te muestra algun error, tambien trata de instalar jquery-migrate-helper en caso de ser algun error de js, intenta depurar el error encontrando que es lo que lo provoca, tambien prueba a desabilitar el plugin de cookie que estas usando 'cookie-notice' el cual parece estar causando problemas de js

Comment: al parecer te está faltando un elemento con id o clase `noticeContainer` si el js de las cookies se carga fuera de tiempo, antes de que exista por ejemplo, puede que no lo encuentre, revisa plugins de cache y minificación